# Solve $\sin x=\sqrt{\frac 2 3}\quad 0\le x\le \pi$ with simple calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

> Solve $\sin x=\sqrt{\frac 2 3}$

Suppose I have a simple calculator and I want to find all the solutions of $\sin x=\sqrt{\frac 2 3}$ between $0$ to $\pi$ how can I do that?

I done: $\text{shift } \sin $ of $\sqrt{\frac 2 3}$ and the calculator gave me the answer $0.981895$

but there is another solution that the calculator didn't gave.

Comment: @πr8 Oh, right, I meant to flip the $x$'s and the $\pi/2$.  Or what you had in the first comment.  :)

Comment: Makes sense - good to clear it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is the first solution, the other solution is $\pi - x$. You can get this from the unit circle.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+sin+x%3Dsqrt(2%2F3)+between+0+to+pi

Comment: @Error404 in your question you ask for the solutions of $\color{blue}{\sin x}=\sqrt{\frac23}$, in the link you ask for the solutions of $\color{red}{x\sin x}=\sqrt{\frac23}$